# Estatégias para coleta de requisitos remotamente

Tags: engenharia-de-software, ddd, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, requisitos

Quando desenvolvemos software uma das principais etapas é a coleta de requisitos, a aquisição de conhecimento do domínio e a construção de uma linguagem ubíqua. Tanto as metodologias ágeis quanto o Domain-Driven Design colocam bastante foco nisso, porque realmente é importante a participação dos especialistas de negócio no desenvolvimento.

Acontece que existem situações em que não é possível estar pessoalmente com os especialistas de negócio para fazer reuniões e discutir o software. Já recebi propostas para desenvolvimento por parte de clientes de outros estados, devido a recomendações de clientes locais, mas fiquei preocupado com relação a essa questão do contato com os especialistas de negócio.

É claro que com a tecnologia que temos hoje deve ser possível uma maneira eficiente para fazer esse contato a distância, mas o que eu quero saber são as técnicas que realmente funcionam. Me parece que só mandar e-mail com um questionário pode não ser o suficiente.

Nesse caso, como podemos fazer remotamente essa parte da coleta de requisitos, aquisição de conhecimento do domínio e construção da linguagem ubíqua? Quais meios para fazer isso realmente funcionam?

Comment: O que posso te dizer é que muitas vezes os tais "especialistas" sabem menos do que parece e na maioria dos casos se você for na onde deles, fará um monstrengo. Uma das coisas que aprendi é que tenho que investigar por meios próprios como funciona, encontrar o modelo, eventualmente discutir quando há capacidade de interlocução de quem é o interessado e testar. A experiência conta muito. Quanto mais faz, mais tem condições de enxergar quando pode confiar no que te passam ou não.

Comment: @bigown Pena que não dá pra dar bounty no seu comment.

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software** (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use os mesmos métodos que usaria normalmente, porém investindo mais esforço para manter a comunicação efetiva.

## Desafios da comunicação à distância

Todo material e todas as pessoas com quem já trabalhei, mesmo quando favoráveis, reconhecem que há desafios no trabalho remoto.

Dificuldades no domínio da língua, atrasos devido a fuso-horários muito diferentes, questões importantes que são evitadas porque você precisa escrever muito, reuniões por video-conferência que se prolongam por causa do atraso na comunicação, conceitos que não são bem explicados porque você não consegue simplesmente pegar um papel e desenhar. Estes são uns poucos itens que são grandes problemas para equipes remotas.

Resumindo: todas as pessoas que conheço relatam que fazer vídeo-conferência não é a mesma coisa que conversar com alguém pessoalmente.

## Esforço redobrado

Para driblar as dificuldades que a distância traz, é necessário haver um esforço maior.

**A distância deve causar um *overhead* de comunicação** e isso deve  refletir no seu prazo e orçamento.

O esforço maior pode ser investido em:

- Mais discussões em vídeo-conferência ou telefone; geralmente se faz o contrário, gasta-se menos tempo do que se faria pessoalmente, mas considerando que a comunicação remota é menos efetiva, é preciso gastar mais tempo se comunicando.
- Repassar cada informação discutida por escrito e enviar para o cliente após as reuniões para confirmação do entendimento.
- Investir em um bom sistema de gerenciamento do seu *backlog* e engajar os interessados para que eles sigam e adicionem comentários.
- Realizar um maior número de demonstrações do software e coletar *feeedback* com maior frequência do que num projeto normal e assim mitigar o mais cedo possível as falhas de comunicação.

Duas observações importantes sobre todos os itens acima:

### 1. Conheça o usuário

O esforço adicional será inversamente proporcional ao conhecimento do usuário sobre TI e sobre suas próprias necessidades.

Antes de começar a levantar as necessidades do cliente, converse com ele para ver o quanto as pessoas envolvidas tem consciência sobre o que estão precisando e se tem alguma experiência em participar de desenvolvimento de sistemas a fim de determinar o trabalho que você vai ter para extrair as informações.

Sempre tome cuidado com o vocabulário usado, pois dependendo do nível do usuário isso vai determinar se a comunicação será mais em nível técnico ou em termos de negócio.

Não é incomum usuários ficarem envergonhados de perguntar sobre algum termo que não conhecem e assim dando respostas enganosas sobre o que eles precisam.

Ao trabalhar remotamente:

- Faça reuniões com todos os usuários para nivelar o conhecimento.
- Faça reuniões individuais com cada interessado e lhes dê a oportunidade de tirar dúvidas "secretamente", sem passar vergonha perante os colegas.
- Ao falar sobre um assunto técnico, sempre resuma para o usuário o que é aquilo, nunca assuma que ele já sabe. Por exemplo: *"A JVM, **aquele programa que você instala para executar aplicativos Java**, blá blá blá"*.

## 2. Corte o papo-furado

Eu falei até agora de gastar mais tempo em comunicação e em reuniões. Isso é algo que parece contraditória e contra-produtivo, afinal quem é que gosta de passar mais tempo em reuniões?

Entretanto, é preciso que todos tenham em mente que este é o preço por usar um meio de comunicação menos efetivo. Mas claro que isso também significa ter a consciência de que o tempo de todos é valioso e reuniões devem ser prolongadas enquanto informações úteis forem obtidas, nunca mais do que isso.

É como fazer o download com menos banda: vai demorar mais tempo para transmitir todos os dados necessários e deve evitar ficar navegando em coisas que não precisa enquanto isso.

Uma dica seria ter poucas reuniões agendadas regularmente e várias reuniões ou "chamadas" informais e sob demanda. Reuniões agendadas são boas de início, mas logo perdem o sentido porque as pessoas não tem muito o que acrescentar e se tornam repetições, então nesse caso é melhor ter os usuários mais perto em conversas irregulares quando dúvidas surgirem.

## Considerações

Enfim, todas as dicas acima são experiências que servem para todos os casos, mas que devem ser mais fortemente reforçados num projeto cuja comunicação é o maior risco.

Aliás, pensando nesse sentido, vale a pena lembrar que dentro de um projeto onde o risco identificado, é sempre bom revisar as técnicas de mitigação relacionadas a esse tipo de risco.